# I need a regex for mysql that will find 10-digit numbers with all the same digits. For example: '8888888888'

Tags: mysql, regex

Anyone actually know how to create a regex for MySQL that can restrict phone numbers with patterns like 0123456789, 8888888888, 9999999999, etc.?

Comment: 0123456789 doesn't have all the same digits?  What's the rule you're trying to implement?

Answer (score 3):

This will detect all-same numbers of at least 8 digits:

```
(\d)\1{7,}
```

To use an a query:

```
select * from mytable
where phone_number rlike '(\d)\1{7,}'
```

(I would check this on sqlfiddle, but it's down - has a bug preventing use)

Comment: Whats with the \1? Backreference to the first group that doesnt exist?

Comment: FYI SQLFiddle is down (has a bug)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer was close.  It's `(\d)\1{9}`.

Note: The reference to the previous answer was relative to the initial version of that answer.

Comment: Again.. whats with the capture groups? Why not just \d{9}?

Comment: @Izkata Whoops, forgot how many digits are in a phone number, hah. Point is, the backreference is pointless.

Comment: why would the backreference be pointless?? you want all ten digits to be equal, \d{10} will give you any ten digits...

Comment: Thank you, @Massa. Too much context switching. Reverted to original answer.

Comment: @Massa Because \d{10} has no back references... so it is not pointless.

Comment: The trouble is that \d{10} matches *any* ten-digit string, even those where the digits are not the same, so it doesn't accomplish the objective. See http://rubular.com/r/qsgy47hHO2

Comment: @Dgrin91 and PeterAlfvin, the question title and body are asking 2 different things, hence some of the confusion (I'd deleted my earlier comment because of that, too)

Comment: @Izkata Ah, I didnt even notice that.